# Azure python api for compute images get(). Adding special character * to the argument 'image_name'

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-python-sdk

I am using Azure ComputeManagementClient.images.get() function to search and match images based on 'resource_group_name' and 'image_name' parameter and print the image details.

[Azure python sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/azure-sdk-overview)

[Azure ComputeManagementClient.images.get()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2023_09_01.operations.imagesoperations?view=azure-python#azure-mgmt-compute-v2023-09-01-operations-imagesoperations-get)

I have azure cli based authentication. 'az login'

Python code:

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
credential = AzureCliCredential()
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential, '<subcribtion_id>')

imagee = compute_client.images.get(resource_group_name='ab-westeurope-image-            
                                     rg',image_name='ubuntu-latest-1707454954')
print(imagee)
```

Image name is in this format: **distro-version-time-stamp**

Actual image name = 'ubuntu-latest-1707454954' where '1707454954' is the time stamp of the image creation.

I am able to print the output(image details) when i give the entire 'image_name'= 'ubuntu-latest-1707454954'

But, when i give special character * in 'image_name' = 'ubuntu-latest-*'
Azure gives output with "Code: ResourceNotFound"

I know, its considering 'image_name' = 'ubuntu-latest-*' as a string to match. But, i want it as asterisk in regex pattern matching.

I get this below error:

```
<!-- azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: (ResourceNotFound) The Resource 'Microsoft.Compute/images/ubuntu-latest-*' under resource group 'ab-westeurope-image-rg' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix
Code: ResourceNotFound
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have below VM images starts with **"ubuntu-latest-"** in resource group named **Sri** like this:

[image]

Note that, Azure SDK for Python doesn't **directly** support wildcard matching for VM image names. When I tried to retrieve these images by adding special character **`*`** , I too got **same error**:

```py
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
credential = AzureCliCredential()
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential, '<subscription_id>')

imagee = compute_client.images.get(resource_group_name='Sri',image_name='ubuntu-latest-*')
print(imagee)
```

**Response:**

[image]

Alternatively, you can make use of below ***modified*** code that initially retrieves list of all images in resource group and filters that response to print matched images:

```py
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential

credential = AzureCliCredential()
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential, '<subscription_id>')

images = compute_client.images.list_by_resource_group(resource_group_name='Sri')
match_string = 'ubuntu-latest-'

for image in images:
    if match_string in image.name:
        print(image.name)
```

**Response:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Sridevi for ur reply, i agree with your soln(listing by resourse_group_name)

I was able to achieve the same using **ResourceManagementClient** and list images by quering the substring to match the image name. Hope this will be helpful to someone looking for the same.

```
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
image_name = "ubuntu-latest"
images_object = resource_client.resources.list(filter=f"resourceType eq 
       'Microsoft.Compute/images' and substringof" f"('{image_name}', name)")}

for image in images_object:
  print(image.name)
```